# Storing the number of iterations of a nested loop in an array

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop, nested

I am relatively new to MATLAB and I am quite stuck in a specific problem.

I have an equation that I am trying to solve using a while loop. It works by guessing a certain parameter e_0 and filling it into the equation, until it converges. An example is found below, where the initial guessing value equals 100:

```
clear all
i=1;
e_0=100
e_1= e_0 + log(0.6) - log(exp(e_0)/(exp(e_0)+1))

    while( i < 1e10 & abs((e_1 - e_0)) > 1e-12),
         i = i + 1;
         e_0=e_1;
         e_1= e_0+log(0.6)-log(exp(e_0)/(exp(e_0)+1))
    end 
i
```

Now I would like the exact same procedure but then for multiple values of e_0 at the same time, e.g. 101, 102, 103 and so on, and count how many more iterations those will take. I reckon that I therefore need to put a for-loop for that. I thought something like this:

```
clear all
i=1;

for e_0 = 100:105
e_1= e_0+log(0.6)-log(exp(e_0)/(exp(e_0)+1))
    while( i < 1e10 & abs((e_1 - e_0)) > 1e-12),
         i = i + 1;
         e_0=e_1;
         e_1= e_0+log(0.6)-log(exp(e_0)/(exp(e_0)+1))
    end 
end
  i
```

However, now all the iterations from the different guessing values are shown underneath each other, and I get a total of 1519 iterations. How can I for example store the number of iterations needed for every initial guessing value underneath each other into a variable?

I hope it is clear enough... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
i = 0;
offset = 99;
for n = 1:6
e_0 = n + offset;
e_1 = e_0+log(0.6)-log(exp(e_0)/(exp(e_0)+1))
    while( i < 1e10 & abs((e_1 - e_0)) > 1e-12),
        i = i + 1;
```

This part needs to change to prevent `e_0` to be redefined inside the loop:

```
        e_1= e_1+log(0.6)-log(exp(e_1)/(exp(e_1)+1)) 
    end 
    iterations(n)=i;
end
```

Note: it is not recommended to use `i` as a loop increment, since it redefines `i` used in complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply! I do get an error message however: "Attempted to access (0.405465); index must be a positive integer or logical."

Comment: @user3594343 That's because you are overwriting the loop variable of the for loop inside the nested loop. You really don't want to do that. Use a different variable instead.

Comment: @user3594343 You should initialize `i` to zero or your loop count will start to count at 2.

Comment: @CapeCode Thank you! I am just not 100% sure whether I can follow. For instance, can I now see how many iterations where needed for the different initial e_0's?

Comment: @user3594343 At the end of each iteration of your `for`-loop, `i` will be written to the n-th element of the array `iterations`, so yes.

Comment: @user3594343 I think this is getting too far off topic now. Please consider making a separate question out of this, illustrating what you changed and why you think that the results you got are not correct.